# How to broadcast a scalar to a filtered column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to broadcast the results of an expression to the a dataframe, but not to the entire column, just to a filtered subset.  A simplification below:

```
In [6]: df1 = DataFrame({"A":[1, 2, 3, 4], "B":["w", "x", "y", "z"], "C":(numpy.
zeros((4), dtype='S1'))})

In [7]: df1
Out[7]:
   A  B C
0  1  w
1  2  x
2  3  y
3  4  z
```

So A and B contain my existing data and column C is prepared to enter my results into. So I can broadcast to the entire column as below:

```
In [9]: df1['C'] = 'H'

In [10]: df1
Out[10]:
   A  B  C
0  1  w  H
1  2  x  H
2  3  y  H
3  4  z  H
```

But if I try and broadcast (in this example, the letter "R") to a filtered subset:

```
In [14]: (df1[df1['A'] > 2])['C']
Out[14]:
2    H
3    H
Name: C
```

(just to prove the filtering works)

so now I try and assign "R" to this subset..

```
In [12]: (df1[df1['A'] > 2])['C'] = "R"

In [13]: df1
Out[13]:
   A  B  C
0  1  w  H
1  2  x  H
2  3  y  H
3  4  z  H
```

But my values remain unchanged :( (though interestingly I do not receive an error!?)
Please can anyone suggest a way I can achieve this?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First choose the column, then filter:

```
df1.loc[df1['A'] > 2, 'C'] = "R"

   A  B  C
0  1  w  H
1  2  x  H
2  3  y  R
3  4  z  R
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as a remark: pandas was nicely improved to give a warning in this case:

```
In [8]: In [12]: (df1[df1['A'] > 2])['C'] = "R"
/Users/tismer/anaconda/bin/ipython:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  #!/bin/bash /Users/tismer/anaconda/bin/python.app
```

[click to read the pandas link from above](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)